# Navigating to views inside CarouselView with Prism

Tags: xamarin.forms, prism

I have a `MyPage` with a `CarouselView` and two buttons below it. The buttons are for navigating between `ContentView` views inside the `CarouselView`:

```
[CarouselView]
[Prev]  [Next]
```

`ContentViewA` and `ContentViewB` are inside of `CarouselView`

The `MyPageViewModel` has commands for the previous and next buttons:

```
class MyPageViewModel : BindableBase
{
    public ICommand ShowPrevCommand { get; private set;}
    public ICommand ShowNextCommand { get; private set;}
}
```

How do I implement the commands to make the `CarouselView` show the views?

According to documentation [here](http://prismlibrary.github.io/docs/xamarin-forms/Navigation-Service.html)

> In Prism, the concept of navigating to a View or navigating to a
>   ViewModel does not exist. Instead, you simply navigate to an
>   **experience**, or a unique identifier, which represents the **target view**
>   you wish to navigate to in your application

so I was thinking I could use INavigationService.
I was thinking I could implement my own `NavigationService` and on `NavigateAsync` I could check if current page is `MyPage`. If it is, I could set the view inside of `CarouselView` to the view based on the navigation name parameter.

I am however not sure how to implement and override Prism's navigation service.

Can Prism for Xamarin Forms do something like this?

Answer (score 1):

It does not have to be that complicated. `CarouselView` has the bindable property `Position`, which you can bind to a property of your viewmodel

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:forms="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.CarouselView">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <forms:CarouselView Position="{Binding CarouselPosition}">
            <!-- whatever to display in the CarouselView -->
        </form:CarouselView>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

In your viewmodel you can implement th navigation the following way:

```
class MyPageViewModel : BindableBase
{
    public MyPageViewModel()
    {
        ShowPrevCommand = new Command(ShowPrev);
        ShowNextCommand = new Command(ShowNext);
    }

    public ICommand ShowPrevCommand { get; private set;}
    public ICommand ShowNextCommand { get; private set;}

    void OnShowPrev()
    {
        CarouselPosition--;
    }

    void OnShowNext()
    {
        CarouselPosition++;
    }

    public int CarouselPosition
    {
        get => _carouselPosition;
        set
        {
            if(value == _carouselPosition)
            {
                return;
            }

            this._carouselPosition = value;
            PropertyChanges?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(CarouselPosition));
        }
    }

}
```

Just to get the gist. Of course you'll have to handle cases like overflows (i.e. `CarouselPosition` exceeds the number of views in the carousel), etc.

Comment: Thanks! You're right, this could definitely work. But using the `Position` property like this makes the view-model look more like code-behind of the view than a view-model. Or maybe you're right, I might be overthinking it, not really sure... I am looking for more thoughts... Using NavigationService instead would really make it more flexibile. But I know this flexibility has a cost (I'd need to implement it myself since Prism doesn't currently support this CarouselView scenario) and second, do I really need it?